# Oracle SQL Syntax: Inner Join

Tags: sql, oracle, syntax, inner-join

I don't have access to an Oracle Database right now, so I'm posting my question here:

Is the following statement valid Oracle SQL Syntax?

```
SELECT a1
FROM t1 INNER JOIN t2
```

I'm particularly wondering whether we need to specify a join attribute for the inner join.

Best,
Will

Comment: or try a natural join if joining column names the same

Comment: Please avoid `natural join`. As APC says below, "it is a bug waiting to happen."

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You're missing `ON`

Like

```
SELECT a1
FROM t1 INNER JOIN t2
ON t1.SomeID = t2.SomeID
```

Answer (score 7):

So, this is the query you're thinking of....

```
SQL> select e.ename
  2         , d.dname
  3  from emp e inner join dept d
  4  /
from emp e inner join dept d
                           *
ERROR at line 3:
ORA-00905: missing keyword


SQL>
```

As we can see, it fails.  The INNER JOIN syntax demands that we provide columns to join on ...

```
SQL> select e.ename
  2         , d.dname
  3  from emp e inner join dept d
  4      on ( d.deptno = e.deptno )
  5  /

ENAME      DNAME
---------- --------------
SCHNEIDER  ACCOUNTING
BOEHMER    ACCOUNTING
KISHORE    ACCOUNTING
ROBERTSON  RESEARCH
...
FEUERSTEIN HOUSEKEEPING
PODER      HOUSEKEEPING
TRICHLER   HOUSEKEEPING

21 rows selected.

SQL>
```

There is an alternative syntax, the NATURAL JOIN.  This syntax will automatically join the two tables on the basis of all columns which share the same name.

```
SQL> select e.ename
  2         , d.dname
  3  from emp e natural join dept d
  4  /

ENAME      DNAME
---------- --------------
SCHNEIDER  ACCOUNTING
BOEHMER    ACCOUNTING
KISHORE    ACCOUNTING
ROBERTSON  RESEARCH
...
FEUERSTEIN HOUSEKEEPING
PODER      HOUSEKEEPING
TRICHLER   HOUSEKEEPING

21 rows selected.

SQL>
```

This is a neat trick but really shouldn't be relied upon in production code; it is a bug waiting to happen.

Answer (score 2):

You will need to add an ON clause

```
SELECT a1
FROM t1 INNER JOIN t2 on t1.a1=t2.a1
```

Answer (score 1):

Yes, you have to specify join condition:

FROM t1 INNER JOIN t2 on t1.f = t2.f